# I am making a job in postgresql using pgagent when I run my job it says coudn't connect to db

Tags: sql, postgresql, jobs, pgagent

I am making a job in postgresql using pgagent when I run my job it says coudn't connect to db. Can any one guide me what is the issue? I tried to find on internet but could not find anything beneficial. I have created my own Database named 'TestDB' . I have only one connection string in pgpass.conf

which is `localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:test`

Comment: Do you actually have Postgres server running?  Can you connect to it using psql?  If your database is "TestDB", then why do you have the database as "postgres"?  If you're on Linux, your pgpass.conf must be 0600.

Comment: Agree, there is something wrong with your connection string and database name.

Comment: @alexherm I added connection string and  correct database name but it still did not work

Comment: @TimRoberts Postgres server is running and I can it with pgadmin 4 . I have created new DB named 'Test DB' but pgpass.conf has this connection string as default. I am using Windows. I changed connection string to 'localhost:5432:TestDB:postgres:test'
as well but same issue

Comment: @alexherm you were right there was an issue with connection string.Thanks

Comment: Go ahead and post the corrected string for others to see.

Comment: Connection String="user=postgres host=localhost port=5432 dbname=TestDB password=test"